# Django - include app urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have the following structure (Django 1.4):

```
containing_dir/
    myproject/
        myapp1/
        myapp2/
        myapp3/
```

myproject, myapp1, myapp2, and myapp3 all have **init**.py, so they're all modules.

In manage.py (under containing_dir) I have `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")`

in myproject.settings i define:

```
[..]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'
INSTALLED_APPS = (   
    [..]
    'myproject.myapp1',
    'myproject.myapp2',
    'myproject.myapp3',
)
[..]
```

In myapp1.urls.py I define:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp1',
    url(r'^agent/$', 'views.agent',    name='agent')
)
```

and I try to import it in myproject.urls I try to import myapp1 urls like this:

```
(r'^myapp1/', include('myproject.myapp1.urls'))
```

but whenever I try lo load `localhost:8000/myapp1/agent` I get

```
Exception Value: No module named myapp1
```

I think thrown from withing myapp1.urls

Any help? thanks

Answer (score 8):

You must have a

```
__init__.py
```

file inside your "myproject" directory. When you say:

```
(r'^myapp1/', include('myproject.myapp1.urls'))
```

you are saying "myproject" (as well as myapp1) is a python packege.

Answer (score 5):

In myproject.settings make following changes :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (   
[..]
'myapp1',
'myapp2',
'myapp3',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^app_name/', include('app_name.urls', namespace='project_name'))
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `ROOT_URLCONF` need to point to `myproject.urls`?

If you place your apps inside of `myproject` you need to use the proper [view prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#the-view-prefix).

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myproject.myapp1',
...
```

Comment: @pistacchio Then you most likely need to create an install script for the apps so that they get added to the python path. Or manually add them.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue just select "myproject" directory in PyCharm and set this as a source root. 
Your project don't know from which root it has to search for given app.
It fixed the issue for me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, In new versions of Django introduces `path(route, view, kwargs=None, name=None)` instead of old `url()` regular expression pattern.

You must have `__init__.py` file in app folders to recognize it as a package by django project i.e myproject

Django project i.e. myproject urls.py file must be updated to include examples like:

```
path('', include('django_app.urls'))
path('url_extension/', include('django_another_app.urls'))
```

Above example includes two apps urls in it. One is without adding any extension to path in url and another is with extension to path in current url.

Also, Do not forget to add django apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` file to recognise it as app by django project something like this.

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
django_app,
django_another_app
...
]
```

For more information look at [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/).