# How to include other app's urls.py in get_absolute_url: reverse() django?

Tags: django, django-urls

In app models.py, I am using `get_absolute_url` to reverse to a particular path using "name" that is in different app urls.py.

But of course I am getting error because the I have not created urls.py for that app as the urlpattern is already present in some other urls.py.

So is there any include(app.urls) type functionality that I can use in reverse?

```
#app: A - urls.py
urlpatterns = [
path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name = 'post-detail'),
...
]

#app: B - models.py
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail',kwargs = {'post_id.id':self.post_id.id})
```

Comment: Have you included these urls in your base app? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885030/django-include-app-urls

Comment: What is the error you're getting? That `kwargs` should be `kwargs={"pk": self.post_id.id}` since that's the placeholder in your `path()`.

Comment: @AKX I was getting ```NoReverseMatch: ```which I thought was for not being able to find urlpattern but it got solved for the same issue you mentioned. I was giving wrong key. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Shamika You're welcome. :) As an aside, there might be something off about your model definition if you have a column with a name that ends with `_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your main urls.py file you have to add all your app urls as follows and call it in your get absolute method. You are defining this method to that particular model only, and is linked to the instance by self.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('your_app.urls')),
]
```

also you can modify your get absolute method as

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail',kwargs = {"pk": self.pk)
```